# Use macros to apply formula to the value in a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I want to automate the process of applying round formula on the same cell.
So if A1 is 33.45 and I apply round formula it becomes =round(33.45,0) with the help of keyboard short-cut.

I ran a macro, changed some things and got the round function apply on the same cell using the below formula.

```
Sub Macro3()
'
'Macro3 Macro
'
'Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+q
'
   Active.Cell.FormulaR1C1 = Round(Active.Cell.FormulaR1C1,0)
    ActiveCell.Offset(1,0).Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

But I cannot get the end result to be written as  =round(cell value,0)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What about `Active.Cell.Value = Round(Active.Cell.Value,0)` ? You can not enter a formula that refers to itself.

Comment: You could also use Activecell.NumberFormat = "0" but that just formatting

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
Sub Macro3()
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=round(" + Str(ActiveCell.Value) + ",0)"
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey! This is great. It work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try to change `Active.Cell.FormulaR1C1 = Round(Active.Cell.FormulaR1C1,0)` to `Active.Cell.FormulaR1C1 = Round(ActiveCell,0)`
by the way, what are you supposed to do with the second statement `ActiveCell.Offset(1,0).Range("A1").Select`? do you want to apply the round to current cell and them move to next line?

Comment: Yes, I want it to move to the next line after the code is finished. It still gives the value directly. But  ActiveCell.Formula = "=round(" + Str(ActiveCell.Value) + ",0)" worked out.
End Sub